# Issue while parsing JWT for claims

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to fetch the roles stored as claim in JWT. I am using following code to do that:

```
   DecodedJWT decodedJWT = JWT.require(Algorithm.HMAC512(SecurityConstants.SECRET.getBytes()))
                    .build()
                    .verify(token.replace(SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX, ""));
  String user = decodedJWT.getSubject();
  Claim claims = decodedJWT.getClaims();
  String roles = claims.get("roles").toString();
```

But this ends up giving object code:

```
 (Value of roles)JSONNodeClaim@10091
```

I debugged the code and found claims like this:

[image]

How can i extract the "ROLE_ADMIN" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the chain method call to get the below:

`String claims = decodedJWT.getClaim("roles").as(TextNode.class).asText();`

Comment: Thanks for your response but there seems to be some error.

Comment: com.auth0.jwt.exceptions.JWTDecodeException: Couldn't map the Claim value to Claim
 at com.auth0.jwt.impl.JsonNodeClaim.as(JsonNodeClaim.java:120) ~[java-jwt-3.4.0.jar:na]

Comment: Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.auth0.jwt.interfaces.Claim` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information

Comment: This worked
String claims = decodedJWT.getClaim("roles").as(TextNode.class).asText();

Comment: great, I could not run it, so had to do with using as() method.

Comment: You can also use the asString method. `decodedJWT.getClaim("roles").asString()`

Comment: Didn't work for me since I cannot cast the object to the JsonNodeClaim class (I cannot import it from my package since it's package private)...

Answer (score 3):

You can cast the claim to the *Claim* class and call the *.asString()* method to return it as a string:

```
String claims = ((Claim) decodedJWT.getClaim("roles")).asString();
```

Comment: thank you!
i was using .toString() and asString() helped me to remove the double qoute issue.
toString => ""mystring""
asString => "mystring"

Answer (score 0):

The roles are always multiple, hence need to call with extraction as a collection

```
List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> simpleGrantedAuthorities = decodedJWT.getClaim("role").asList(SimpleGrantedAuthority.class);
```